# How do I remove white space using CSS?

Tags: html, css, removing-whitespace

The question and answers have custom defined div wrappers around them.

The closing div  is on the next line producing a blank line.
I want to remove that line.

Post Link: http://fgstudy.com/uncategorized/a/

I have already tried the white-space CSS code as followed:

```
div#q1, div#a1, div#a2 { white-space: normal; }
P { white-space: normal;}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 2% 2%;
}

#q1 {
  margin: 10px 10px;
  border: 1px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 2px #DCDCDC;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #317eac;
}

#a1 {
  margin: 10px 10px;
  border: 1px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 2px #DCDCDC;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 8px 18px;
}

#a2 {
  margin: 10px 10px;
  border: 1px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 2px #DCDCDC;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 5px 18px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#a1:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #73AD21;
}

#a2:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #C71C22;
}
```

```html
<hr>
<div id="q1">
  <p>Which of the following the highest hydration energy</p>
</div>
<div id="a1">
  <p>Mg<sup>++</sup></p>
</div>
<div id="a2">
  <p>Li<sup>+</sup></p>
</div>
<div id="a2">
  <p>Na<sup>+</sup></p>
</div>
<div id="a2">
  <p>K<sup>+</sup></p>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="q1">
  <p>Which the correct statement</p>
</div>
<div id="a1">
  <p>Na<sup>+</sup>is smaller than Na atom</p>
</div>
<div id="a2">
  <p>Cl<sup>-</sup>is smaller than Cl atom</p>
</div>
<div id="a2">
  <p>Cl<sup>-</sup>(Ion) and Cl (atom) are equal in size</p>
</div>
<div id="a2">
  <p>Na<sup>+</sup>is larger than Na atom</p>
</div>
```

I want that the white space after text disappears.

Comment: The whitespace is being caused by the margin on the paragraph, not the newline of the closing `</div>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the margin from p tag to remove the blank space below the text

```
p {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the paragraph inside each `div` has a `margin-bottom` property set.

Something like `.entry-content p { margin-bottom: 0; }`will get rid of it, or to be more specific: `.entry-content > div p { margin-bottom: 0; }`