# Remove footer white space on the left and right side

Tags: css, width, footer

I'm trying to remove the white space on the right and left side of my footer, it keeps making it when I put the code "max-width: 1200px; margin: auto;" to center the content. What other ways can I center the content and at the same time remove the white gaps on both sides?

I tried using margin-top, margin-left, margin-right, bootstrap's pull-left and pull-right, margin and padding set to 0, width:100% etc. Nothing worked.

Thanks.

My code is this:

```
body {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

footer{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.footer-distributed{
    background-color: #2c2c2c;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    font: normal 16px 'Varela Round';
    padding: 20px 50px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
 
.footer-distributed .footer-left,
.footer-distributed .footer-center,
.footer-distributed .footer-right, .mapouter .gmap_canvas{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
 
.footer-distributed .footer-left{
    width: 40%;
}
 
.footer-distributed h3{
    color:  #ffffff;
    font: normal 36px 'Varela Round', cursive;
    margin: 0;
}
 
.footer-distributed h3 span{
    color:  #ffffff;
}
 
 
.footer-distributed .footer-links{
    color:  #ffffff;
    margin: 20px 0 12px;
    padding: 0;
}
 
.footer-distributed .footer-links a{
    display:inline-block;
    line-height: 1.8;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:  inherit;
}
 
.footer-distributed .footer-company-name{
    color:  #8f9296;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
}
 
 
.footer-distributed .footer-center{
    width: 35%;
    padding-top:18px;
}
 
.footer-distributed .footer-center i{
    background-color:  #33383b;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 42px;
    margin: 10px 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
 
.footer-distributed .footer-center i.fa-envelope{
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 38px;
}
 
.footer-distributed .footer-center p{
    display: inline-block;
    color: #ffffff;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin:0;
}
 
.footer-distributed .footer-center p span{
    display:block;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:2;
}
 
.footer-distributed .footer-center p a{
    color:  #cd2030;
    text-decoration: none;
}
 
.footer-distributed .footer-right{
    width: 20%;
    padding-top:18px;
}
 
.footer-distributed .footer-company-about{
    line-height: 20px;
    color:  #92999f;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0;
}
 
.footer-distributed .footer-company-about span{
    display: block;
    color:  #ffffff;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
 
.footer-distributed .footer-icons{
    margin-top: 25px;
}
 
.footer-distributed .footer-icons a{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color:  #33383b;
    border-radius: 2px;
 
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 35px;
 
    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
 
 
@media (max-width: 880px) {
 
    .footer-distributed{
        font: bold 14px 'varela round';
    
    }
    
    .copyright-info, .credit {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
    }
 
    .footer-distributed .footer-left,
    .footer-distributed .footer-center,
    .footer-distributed .footer-right{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
        text-align: center;
    }
 
    .footer-distributed .footer-center i{
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    .main {
        line-height: normal;
        font-size: auto;
    }
 
}
```

Comment: This question has already been asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57055317/remove-white-space-using-css

Answer (score 2):

Use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). All the elements within your footer will automatically center within the parent.

```css
footer {
  background-color: #2c2c2c;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.footer-distributed {
  padding: 1em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
}
```